# Issues with ESlint for Javascript in Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, eslint

We have enabled ESLint in one of our project which use RoR as the underlying framework. We are using rails' asset pipeline for asset management which uses following syntax (see `asset_path` function)

```
<img src='<%= asset_path("banner.jpg") %>' alt='banner image'>
```

The issue here is while running lint checks it throws following error:

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token %=
```

Is there a way I can let `ESLint` allow to *parse* `<%=`?

Comment: ESLint is for linting JavaScript code. This is ERB code inside HTML code. Why do you want ESLint to do anything at all with this file?

Comment: Yeah this is HTML but we inject some of HTML through JS. Plus there are other places like `<%= Rails.env.production? %>` too where we use ERB code.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html-erb

Just install via npm or yarn and then add to your `.eslintrc` file:

```
  "plugins": [
    "html-erb"
  ],
```